# Set a condition for one field to be unique in all the content types.

Tags: views, rules

I am working with Drupal 8, and have a custom post type called: chapter. This content type is connected with a taxonomy term called: Book.

Now, I have a field called: number, for specifying the chapter one, two or three. **this field should be unique.** For example, if I say chapter 1 I can not repeat it ever again in the same book, but I can upload the chapter 1 for another book. I also can upload all the chapters for the same book in a different order.

So the rule is: Just add a unique chapter number per book.

The final goal is to create a view and be able to order my chapters by the number.

Do I have to use the rules module for that? Or maybe, there is a better approach?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a custom validation constraint and a hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter to set the new constraint to your field.

Check: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint